# User league information missing in the profile page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, reputation-leagues, user-rank

It seems like the "Top 0.18% this month" or similar links are no longer displayed in the user profile pages. Is this a bug or a feature?

I personally found the information under these links very useful.

It does appear here on Meta but missing on other sites.

Comment: Hmm. I just see that link yesterday or a day before yesterday. But today, the link is not available.

Comment: Hmmm, it's there on MSO but not SO.

Comment: Until this is fixed you can manually navigate to: http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow

Comment: It sounds like a good plan. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is intentional for the moment, we have an issue with the leagues population causing an inordinate amount of load on our SQL servers which I have yet to find time to investigate.

I just turned it on for Stack Overflow specifically, it's the SE 2.0 sites causing the SQL issue...Stack Overflow is fine.

We've been a little busy wit the failover to our redundant Datacenter the past 2 days getting the last bits of the network stood up (that you guys don't see).  Tomorrow I'll try and track down the cause of the crazy reads on the league queries and deploy a fix.  Apologies this has lingered a few days, but we have to triage a bit at the moment due to Sandy moving up our time tables drastically.

Comment: I cannot see the information at the moment on SO. I didn't want to ask a question and have it linked here as a duplicate so I figured I would post this as a comment. Is the lack of "top %" right now for a similar reason as posted in this answer?

Comment: @TravisJ - there was an issue this morning with SE.com performance, it's been since resolved...you should be seeing the link on profiles, can you hard refresh and see if it comes up please?

Comment: Confirmed, it is showing now.

Comment: @NickCraver: Should that be marked [status-completed] now since you deployed a fix? I noticed [it is still not working](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203785/missing-reputation-league)