# What happened to OnStartups' meta site?

Tags: support, per-site-meta

The [meta site for OnStartups](http://meta.answers.onstartups.com) has disappeared. What happened?

Late last night I tried to access meta.answers.onstartups.com, but I received a message from Stack Exchange saying that it was undergoing maintenance. At first, I assumed it was a network-wide thing, and thought it might have something to do with Hurricane Sandy. But then I was able to browse to MSO and the main OnStartups site just fine.

Today I tried meta.answers.onstartups.com again, and now my browser is behaving like the site no longer exists. Even stranger, the meta link is now missing from the header on the main OnStartups site.

[image]

What’s going on? Did Sandy sweep away the OnStartups’ meta site?

Comment: I wish Meta Programmers would disappear too...

Comment: So much for 30 consecutive days...

Comment: *You need at least 8k reputation to access OnStartup Meta*...

Comment: @ChrisGerken missing days due to downtime [has been addressed in the past](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67109/proposal-free-day-in-the-visit-log-to-account-for-the-oct-9th-downtime).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Physics Meta is missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330649/physics-meta-is-missing)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We don't have control over onstartups DNS, and [we failed over to Oregon due to sandy](http://blog.serverfault.com/2012/10/30/failing-over-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-for-sandy/). For now, it is probably better to leave it be as we may fail back to NY soon.

Once we have a better idea about our long term plan, we will let the DNS maintainer know what to do.

Comment: Any chance sandy is responsible [for this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153042/user-league-information-missing-in-the-profile-page) as well?

Comment: So you're now back to the NY datacenter, but you don't think it's sustainable right now?

Comment: @ZulyGonzalez: Typo, should have said "fail back to NY"

Comment: Any idea when this will be resolved?

Comment: @ZulyGonzalez: The maintainer says he just updated the record, might take a while to take effect depending on the TTL setting

Comment: Thanks for the update.