# Multiple sites failing to list questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, question-lists

I tried to go to the [Physics meta site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com) and was greeted with:

[image: broken meta site]

Not sure what is happening, or how long it has happened/will continue...

---

It looks like it happened to [another main beta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330649/per-site-metas-failing-to-list-questions#comment1078732_330649) as well:

[image: hardware rec failure]

which again came back quickly based on the comment.

Both sites are back working now though, but since it happened more than once, there may be something happening on the backend that should be investigated.

---

And at 9am Eastern time (10 July 2019), the main physics site also had the problem:

[image: physics main site failure]

Comment: That looks like the server just had a hiccup and failed to load that one time. Did you try refreshing the page and consistently got that error message?

Comment: @animuson I tried refreshing (and incognto mode also) for about 3 minutes and kept getting it. It's back now, though.

Comment: @animuson FYI I just had the same issue (for a few seconds) on [hardwarerecs.se]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqKXe.png Voting to reopen - I can't remember the last time this happened.

Comment: @Glorfindel  Duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153084/what-happened-to-onstartups-meta-site (from 2012).

Comment: @Rob I guess based on the title it's similar, but it seems like the symptoms are very different, so it's probably not a duplicate.

Comment: tpg2114 over there, it's not clear what the problem was, but it looks like each server had two different copies of it's files and when it failed over the way the site operated was changed. **Here** we don't know what the problem is, yet. Glorfindel said: "I can't remember ..." and I directed the comment to him. If I flagged your question as a dupe you would see a close(1) flag on it. No one's saying "It's a dupe" and even if it was identical in every way people still need to file a new report and not expect the devs to search 7 year old complaints to discover a bug on a different server today.

Comment: Maybe the tagengine blipped...

Comment: @animuson Physics main site just did it too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be resolved. We have increased the error logging in the tag engine to capture if this happens again, but as a part of the move to .NET Core all of the tag engine is being replaced and is actually [in the process of rolling out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330837/164200).

We'll be monitoring the rollout of the new code and hopefully will spot this if it happens again.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same thing as [this other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330837/152859)? If so, probably better mark this as duplicate, no?

Comment: @ShaWiz Sort of, this was reported before we started the rollout of the new tag engine. The other one was because of the rollout . We had no error logging to capture whatever triggered this issue. Our assumption is that what was reported here should be resolved, but it most definitely will be because we're replacing all the tag engine code.

Comment: @Taryn This same message is coming up again repeatedly right now... Do I need to open a new Meta post?

Comment: @tpg2114 I'm investigating

Comment: @Taryn Thanks -- another mod mentioned it happened for sites besides Physics. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: @tpg2114 It should be resolved now. I can load Physics again, can you confirm if it's working on your end?

Comment: @Taryn I can load it. I'll let you know if it comes up again (hopefully not!)

Comment: @Taryn Something related just happened on Physics Meta: "The data for the tag search is still loading; please retry in a moment." Hopefully this is throwing log messages somewhere!

Comment: @tpg2114 It should be back in working order now. We pushed a change to the servers running the Tag Engine which resulted in a blip in the service. I'm not seeing additional exceptions at this time .

Comment: @Taryn Okay, this time I promise to really not bug you anymore! (knock on wood!)

Comment: This happened for a few minutes today on [Ask Ubuntu Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/) but (as of a minute or so ago) it appears resolved. I'm not sure if it should be considered a problem or not.

Comment: Hi @Taryn -- I am getting this issue again on Physics at this moment. Just an FYI in case there's something that can be tracked or looked into!