# Why does sometime a question only get visible publicly after 3-6 min of posting?

Tags: support, questions, newest-questions, visibility

As far as I have observed, after posting a question, the post is not publicly visible for like 3-6 mins or maybe less. After that, the question shows up.
However, the question is visible to those who have opened one of the tag tagged in the question (looking at *Newest '{tag}' questions*) for a long period of time. The question shows up in the queue on clicking *'question with a new activity'*. But if we refresh the page, it will be no longer in the queue, unless the page is refreshed in a few seconds after the appearance of the question in the queue. That question will appear in the queue some min later and it'll be publicly visible.

Moreover, I have also felt it happening on my own questions. Whenever I posted a question, I almost don't get any reply and there is no effect on the views, but after a few mins, there is wave of notifications.

What is the reason behind all this? Why does a new question post **sometime** not show up immediately on posting?

Comment: Caching.  It's always caching.

Comment: Or this bug again: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330833/295232

Comment: I don't have any documentation but I'm under the impression that it's by design that posts will be hidden for the first n minutes unless you're already sitting on the home page and see the "n active questions" banner.

Comment: @Catija I've seen it range from a few seconds to a couple minutes, so it's probably caching. (It's worth noting that the Questions page is cached significantly less.)

Comment: Home page is a bit slow to update as compared to the tab Questions ->Active/newest.