# Overall Reputation Link missing

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, user-rank

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User league information missing in the profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153042/user-league-information-missing-in-the-profile-page)

I noticed today that the **top x% month** link is missing from my profile summary page.  This was present yesterday and disappeared at some point during the night.  I have cleared my cache and can replicate this in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

[image]

Is this a new change as I notice it is missing on other Stack sites including DBA.SE (but not meta)?  Where did it go?

Comment: @TimStone argh, I didn't see that one.  I did search though, sorry for the clutter