# Are "Top X%" stats displayed for StackExchange sites?

Tags: support, profile-page

On my SO profile summary page, I have a "top X% this quarter" above my reputation graph.

I've never seen this stat on my stack exchange accounts, is it only displayed on SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to show on all sites, until it "started causing an inordinate amount of load on the SQL servers".

Source: [Nick answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153131/152859) in [User league information missing in the profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153042/user-league-information-missing-in-the-profile-page)

When this will be fixed, the stats will be back on all sites where you have more than 200 rep.