# Missing Reputation League

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, reputation-leagues

The link to the reputation league is missing in the profile page on first load. After a page refresh the link shows normally on SO and MSO but not on other SE sites.

[image: Missing league]

On other sites like Serverfault.com or SuperUser.com the link is still missing even after a refresh.

Comment: Btw, I can see "[top 0.51% this year](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/year/meta-stackoverflow/2013-01-01/172011#172011)".

Comment: The answer in that duplicate indicates it is fixed by now which seems to be not.

Comment: The link is there after the ajax call, but blank text...investigating

Comment: This was a fun localization bug to track down - a fix should roll out shortly

Comment: This is not a dupe btw.

Comment: [Localisation again...](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelb958/vSfXT/show/#localisation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix is rolling out now, thanks to Nick.